# Selecting a subsection of jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Given table `events`:

```sql
create table events (
  id integer,
  data jsonb
)
```

How would one construct a query such that we return only select keys in the results column?

say we had the record in the `events` table:

```
(1, {"a": 1, "b": 2})
```

Is it possible to return something like:

```
id | data
1  | {"b": 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward, using `jsonb_build_object`:

```sql
create temporary table events(id, data) 
as values (1, '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":"three"}'::jsonb);

select id, jsonb_build_object(
  'b', data -> 'b', 
  'c', data -> 'c'
) from events;
```

| id | jsonb_build_object |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"b": 2, "c": "three"} |